# change label text in derived form where label located in base form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to windows forms in C# I am developing a windows form application and i put a base form in my project so other forms inheriting the base form have the controls of base form...

i have a Main Form inherits the base form and the base form have a label control that showing the username on the top of every form i create. the problem is i don't know how i can change the label text in the forms derived from base form.

i need to change the label text in login form which is a separated form showing on startup after splash showed

is there any way to do this???

because of security reasons i can not put the code here but i really need help. so please help me ....

Comment: Are you trying to change one form from within another? or are you trying to set data in a base form from the child?  if the latter, then my answer should help.  Let me know if i've missed the mark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you might have code like this:

A form that inherits from a base and you want to set the value of the control.

```
public partial class Form2 : BaseForm
{
    public Form2()
    {
        this.textBox1.Text = "my stuff";
    }

}
```

The base class has a designer class where the controls are declared.

By default, the controls are declared as `private`

```
public partial class BaseForm: Form
{
    //declared by default in .designer.cs
    //private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
    //change to:
    protected System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
    }
}
```

If the control is set to `protected` or `public` then the child classes will be able to access and change their values.

Comment: I think it's possible using the VS form designer to multiselect form controls and set their Visibility property to `protected`. In general I suggest `protected` is better than `public` because the latter allows any object that references the form to modify its publicly visible controls.

Comment: Agreed, protected is the better choice generally.